Calculate resistor value in Zener clipper circuit
I'm trying to build a circuit which drives one of two LEDs from a variable voltage power supply, which can range between -15 to +15 volts. I'd like the LED to hit maximum brightness as early as possible in the voltage curve, and to not burn out when the supply voltage exceeds the Vf of the diode.
I'm thinking a Zener clipping circuit would be ideal. For example, using a pair of 2.4v Zeners, I believe they should clip at +/-3.1v.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
First question - would that circuit work as I expect it to?
Second question - what should R1 be?
The power supply is capable of delivering a couple of amps at up to 15 or so volts, positive or negative biased.

As your circuit is drawn, only 1 LED will come on. Try something like this. The values will need to be adjusted.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab



Thanks! This version of the circuit worked best for me, as my red/white LEDs have different Vf ratings, with a bit of resistor fiddling, it works decently. Strangely, as the voltage rises, the current to the LED still increases, so it does continue to get brighter after initially illuminating, but it's good enough for my needs, thanks!

Try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This should get the LED's to come on at lowest voltages in the range. It's not very efficient. But it's super simple. You can split the two LED branches so their currents can be controlled independently if that really matters.

Thanks for this - you were actually first with an answer, but I needed different resistors for my LEDs, which is why the other answer was the accepted one. But yours definitely helped!

Here's an alternative approach that does not waste as much power. Maximum power dissipation in each transistor is ~110mW. In this simulation, a (likely visible) 0.5mA is achieved at about +/-1.6V. Anything much less than that would require some kind of boost converter or similar circuit.

One downside is that the current is not well specified but it may be good enough for a visual indicator.
Each JFET works similarly to an old-style current regulator diode with the voltage across the 22Ω resistor serving to produce a negative gate-source voltage reduce the  'constant' current below the Idss of the JFET.
Only a single transistor regulates in a given direction of current and the other one conducts more strongly. Due to symmetry the same resistor can be shared by the two JFETs.
Depletion-mode N-channel MOSFETs could be used similarly.
The LEDs are connected back-to-back so one conducts current in each direction. The opposing LED Vf when conducting also keeps the reverse-bias voltage of the 'off' LED from getting high enough to potentially cause breakdown.

Shouldn't it at least mention what the two transistors do?

Unfortunately I don't have any JFETs handy to try this one, but definitely willing to give it a go in the future.
